# How to place libc.a objects in specific output sections in a GCC LD script?

Tags: memory, static-libraries, ld, libc, map-files

I'm trying to place libc functions like `memcpy`, `memset` etc in specific sections of memory.
I tried doing smth like this:

```
.section1
{
    /path/to/libc.a
    otherobj.o
}
.section2
{
    *(.text)
}

.section3
{
    *(.data .bss)
}
```

using gcc's ld tool with this script and the -map option, I check out the mapfile generated and see that `memcpy` and other symbols still appear in sections 2 and 3.

## WORKAROUND:

Finally i just extracted the lib file to its collection of object files and placed them individually where i liked.

Comment: Why? What are you *really* trying to do? This sounds a lot like [the XY problem](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem).

Comment: My problem is literally trying to put the libc code in a specific section of memory which is faster.  I use static linking and must place only the libc code in that section and nothing else.